# How to get RSTP video link from Dailymotion?

Tags: android, video-streaming, dailymotion-api

Is there a way to get video link from Dailymotion like this link for Youtube

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/+code+?alt=json

Is there an equivalent for Dailymotion ? I search but I didn't find any direct link...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dailymotion doesn't provide rtsp streams anymore. You can instead ask the API for MP4 streams and HLS streams.

Here is an example :

https://api.dailymotion.com/video/x1ysf8a?fields=id,title,stream_hls_url

You can find a complete documentation here : http://www.dailymotion.com/doc/api/graph-api.html

Please note that in order to get access to the streams you need to become a content-partner. Without the correct authorizations, the API will not give you the streams. You should contact Dailymotion here : http://publisher.dailymotion.com/en/

Comment: Thank you but I find an other way to do what I want with the embed link of dailymotion and a WebView. But thank you for your time and your answer, it'll be useful later for me.

Comment: could you please tell us the solution ?